# What is a good example of a jquery mobile layout for Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, haml

Below is what I'm using as my main layout for a Rails project targeting mobile devices. I derived the page, header, content, and footer data-roles per the jquery mobile docs. Does anyone with jquery mobile experience see any glaring deficiencies in the following haml layout?

```
!!! 5
%html

  %head
    %title= h(yield(:title))
    %meta{"http-equiv"=>"Content-Type", :content=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}/
    %meta{:name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}/
    = stylesheet_link_tag "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"
    = yield(:head)

  %body
    .app_page{"data-role" => :page, "data-theme" => :b}
      = yield(:header)

      .app_content{"data-role" => :content}
        ~ yield

      .app_footer{"data-role" => :footer}
        = yield(:footer)
```

Comment: Note: I'm purposefully allowing each page template to specify the contents of its header section for things like showing the back button, or not. That's why yield(:header) is not nested under a header div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make sure your header is in a div with `"data-role"=>:header`, but otherwise your layout looks correct.

What makes you think it has deficiencies? It appears to follow jquery-mobile's spec for page objects, and there's nothing Rails-specific to consider for layout.

Comment: Thanks, Dominic.  I'm using content_for around the yield :header to allow each template to be page-specific for things like whether or not to show a back button.  It wasn't until I read the docs several times that I noticed that each page element needs a unique ID for internal linking.  So, wondered what else I might be missing.